# How to keep server session active based on user activity on the browser with basic ajax call to server without JQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, session

The server session Timeout is 30 minutes in my site.

```
<system.web>
      <sessionState timeout="30" />
 </system.web>
```

But if the user is active on the browser by typing a long comment or selecting a few checkboxes, I need to keep the user active without logging out.
when the user became inactive after 10 mins of typing, goes away for 20 minutes comes back to type again the user should not be logged out since the idle time is just 20 not 30 mins but user should be logged out if he had been gone for 30 whole mins.I found the below code to check user activity. The code works if I do not have the above mentioned line in web.config which I think is wrong. I want to keep that and also prevent the timeout from happening if the user is active on the browser.Also I do not want to simply redirects the user to logout.aspx. I want to end the server session. is there a solution for this without having to create dummy aspx page or is it must to keep an empty page to avoid 404? Any solution with basic Ajax call to server without using Jquery? Thanks!!

```
var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 60; //seconds
var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
document.onclick = function() {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};
document.onmousemove = function() {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};
document.onkeypress = function() {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};
window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);

function CheckIdleTime() {
    _idleSecondsCounter++;
       if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
        alert("Time expired!");
        document.location.href = "logout.aspx";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the http option method.

```
function keepOnline(url) {
  var xhr ;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.open("OPTION",url,true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```